# How can I merge two datasets?

Tags: datasets, data-preprocessing

I want to merge 2 data sets in one, but don't know the right approach to do it. The datasets are similar, the last column is the same - will or not them buy a product. In the first dataset, users who only will buy, in second - only who won't buy.

The 1st dataset contains 500 rows and 2nd 10000 rows. What will be the right approach to merge it? How can I normalize them? And to point for an algorithm that the last column is the main sequence on what it should learn?

Example:

```
id    income date will_buy

23123 200    10.5 Yes
```

and second dataset:

```
id    income date will_buy

2323  100    10.5 No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) function:

```
final = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

To set the last column as labels, you set them as so by:

```
labels = np.array(final["will_buy"])
```

So, when calling the `fit` method on the model you build, you set `labels = labels`.